# How can I use my hash keys as regexes to retrieve values?

Tags: perl

```
%s = (  t2* => [ a,b,x],
        IAm => 'ALL' ) ;

my $key = 't2000' ;
```

In the example above, `t2*` matches `$key`, but I cannot retrieve the corresponding hash value.

What is the best method to retrieve values when the key is a regex?

Comment: You're going to have to explain a bit better.

Comment: I don't want to use external module please

Comment: Oh, I see.. you think `t2*` means that any key that begins with `t2` will match.

Comment: @joe : I edited the question to make it clearer for others. If this is not the question you had in mind please feel free to edit it.

Comment: `t2*` doesn't match `t2000`, did you mean `t20*`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sound like you want [Tie::RegexpHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aRegexpHash), which allows you to assign a value to a hash key that's a regular expression, and then retrieve the value by passing any key that matches the regular expression. Example from the docs:

```
use Tie::RegexpHash;

my %hash;

tie %hash, 'Tie::RegexpHash';

$hash{ qr/^5(\s+|-)?gal(\.|lons?)?/i } = '5-GAL';

$hash{'5 gal'};     # returns "5-GAL"
$hash{'5GAL'};      # returns "5-GAL"
$hash{'5  gallon'}; # also returns "5-GAL"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean up this question. I think you are doing something wrong, but I'll try to answer.

```
my %s = ( qr/t2*/ => [ qw/ a b x / ], IAm => 'ALL' );
my $key = 't2000';
my @matches = ();
while ( my ( $regex_key, $value ) = each( %s ) ) {
    push @matches, $value if $key =~ $regex_key;
}
```

I don't know if this is what you want though. It looks ugly.

Also, if you intend to insert a regex in to the hash, use the 'qr' function to wrap the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following implementation relies on the assumption that the key specified can only ever match a *single* key in the hash.

```
%s = (
       t20* => [ a,b,x],
       IAm => 'ALL'
     ) ;

my $value = 't2000';

my $result = value_pattern_hash ( \%s, $value );

sub value_pattern_hash {

    my ( $hash, $key ) = @_;

    foreach my $pattern ( keys %s ) {

        next unless $key =~ /$pattern/;  # NOTE: quotemeta would break this
        return $hash->{$pattern};
    }

    return;  # In case of a failed match, returns undef or empty list
}
```

If multiple matches wish to be returned, a simple `map`/`grep` combo will do the trick:

```
my @results = map { $s{$_} } grep { $value =~ /$_/ } keys %s;
```